# Is there a term for a send+recv or request+response pair?

Tags: sockets, networking, request, response, terminology

Is there a term for "one turn of communication", ie. a request and a response pair, in networking or IPC?

For example in sockets,

```
# a pair = ?
sock.send(...)
sock.recv(4096)
```

Comment: @EJP it is too closely tied in association to database systems, if you ask me. Also in that sense, the atomicity of it with sockets may would be up to debate. Possible to use, but too loose/problematic, in my opinion.

Comment: Nevertheless it is the answer to your question. If you have additional constraints you should have specified them in your question.

Comment: @EJP I see! Thanks for the clarification, then. I may need to re-think my question based on this.